# Search bar with VisNetwork Graph in Shiny

Tags: r, graph, shiny, shinydashboard

I have built a network graph with VisNetwork and Shiny. I am very pleased with the results.  What I would like to do is use a search bar (for example: http://projects.flowingdata.com/tut/interactive_network_demo/) to search the nodes in my data.

I am using shinydashboard.  So I tried to use the "sidebarSearchForm". However, when I run the app and try to use the search form, nothing is returned.

Here is my code for the ui:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Network", tabName = "network", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      sidebarSearchForm(textId = "searchText", buttonId = "searchButton", label = "Search...")
   )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(
      title = "Network",  status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
      visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = 700)  
    )
  )
)#end ui
```

Here is the code for the server;

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(my.nodes, my.edges, height = "100%")
  })
  output$searchString <- renderText({
    if (input$searchButton == 0)
      return()
    isolate({input$searchString})
  })
} #end server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `visNetworkProxy` and `visSelectNodes` for example, like this with a simple `grepl` :

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = c("A", "B", "A"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

require(visNetwork)
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Network", tabName = "network", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                        sidebarSearchForm(textId = "searchText", buttonId = "searchButton", label = "Search...")
                      )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      box(
                        title = "Network",  status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,
                        visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = 700)
                      )
                    )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "100%")
  })

  observe({
    if(input$searchButton > 0){
      isolate({
        print(input$searchText)
        current_node <- nodes[grep(input$searchText, nodes$label), "id"]
        print(current_node)
        visNetworkProxy("network_proxy") %>% visSelectNodes(id  = current_node)
      })
    }
  })

} #end server

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but the search bar still returns nothing.

Comment: If you use searchButton, you have to click on the icon to enable change

Comment: Thanks. When I click it, it selects all of the nodes in the network.

Comment: Silly mistake on my end. I needed to used the correct dataframe with my network data. Also I made it case insensitive and an exact match with:Also, I used a which statement to get an exact match: current_node <- network$x$nodes[which(network$x$nodes$id == input$searchText),"label"]. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to edit my comment but I couldn't do it... Your solution worked... I was able to get an exact match that was case insensitive with: `find_me <- paste0("^",input$searchText,"$")` and then `current_node <-  network$x$nodes[grep(find_me, network$x$nodes$id, ignore.case = T), "label"]`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this:

http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/shiny.html

Check `visNetworkProxy` section.

Also, the demo code comes with the package has the thing you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  I have looked at that.  I have implemented the nodesIdSelection and SelectedBy options.  But I don't see how to create a search bar, where the user can type in the name of the node.

Answer (score 0):

The above code from bthieurmel can be modified to the below to enable search that is not case sensitive:

```
current_node <- nodes[grep(input$searchText, nodes$label, ignore.case = T), "id"]
```